# 4.7.14 Upgrade: Custom fields missing from views' filter criteria

Tags: contacts, drupal-views, civicrm-entity

Noticed this this morning after upgrading to 4.7.14 yesterday, so I believe there's a connection, but can't confirm 100%.

I have a view that shows how many contact records (that have a custom field 'Leader') are marked Yes. That's done by doing a distinct count on contact IDs, and then using the custom field to filter those.

This has worked absolutely fine until the upgrade, and now views does not show that custom field in the filter criteria. (FYI, I am also using CiviCRM entity and the entity field shows there)

I have experienced similar before, so have went and replaced by CMS database integration code in settings.php to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd experienced similar,, but its inconsistent..custom fields on contacts seem to work but I can't get  events participants or membership to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This relates to [CRM-19545](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19545).  [PR-417](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/417) will hopefully be released in 4.7.16 but until then, you could apply the patch to restore the previous functionality.